# Laravel - path to store classes for working with filesystem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I need to create my own class for working with large files.
It will be based on yield operator.
Laravel has no such functionality. (I didn't find, if you can point something that's fine. Question is about proper place to  store custom class)

I've read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/structure .

Where would be a good place for such class to store?

Probably something like `app/filesystem/FileSystemBigfile.php` ?

Would it be fine if I store all other my classes regarding filesystem in the mentioned folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put this file but you should use PSR-4 so instead of:

```
app/filesystem/FileSystemBigfile.php
```

you should rather use:

```
app/Filesystem/FileSystemBigfile.php
```

I personally use services and for non-standard things I have `Services` directory, so I would use for example:

```
app/Services/Filesystem/FileSystemBigfile.php
```

for that.

Comment: ah, Services folder reminds me of Components  folder in yii